# comparing the two values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, inequality

Suppose $0<a<1$ and $x>0$. The symbol $int(x)$ returns the maximum integer that is no greater than $x$. Would someone tell us which of the following two values is larger?

1. $3 \times int({\log}_2 \log_a x)$
2. $2 \times int({\log_a x})-2$

Comment: If $x\ge 1$ the first value is not even defined (as a real number). Do you want to limit $x$ to $0<x<1$?

Comment: @Rory Daulton, Oh, yes, $0<x<1$.

Comment: @Macavity, why do we need to restrict $a\le x<1$?

Comment: @JohnSmith No need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=\log_a x$. Here I drew the graph of $Y=3\lfloor\log_2 X\rfloor$ (red line) and $Y=2\lfloor X\rfloor -2$ (blue line). Note that if $X$ is sufficiently large, $X\gg\log_2 X$.

[image]